# Existe alguma função que preenche uma string até determinado comprimento?

Tags: javascript, string

Gostaria de preencher uma *string* até chegar em um determinado comprimento. Existe alguma função capaz de fazer isso?

Seria algo parecido com o [`PadLeft(Int32,Char)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx) e [`PadRight(Int32,Char)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/36f2hz3a(v=vs.110).aspx) do C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Funcionando em qualquer versão do JavaScript.

```js
function padRight(str, len, char) {
    if (typeof(char) === 'undefined') {
        char = ' ';
    }
    len = len + 1 - str.length
    len = len  > 0 ? len : 0
    return Array(len).join(char) + str;
}

function padLeft(str, len, char) {
    if (typeof(char) === 'undefined') {
        char = ' ';
    }
    len = len + 1 - str.length
    len = len  > 0 ? len : 0
    return str + Array(len).join(char);
}

console.log(padLeft("teste", 8));
console.log(padLeft("teste", 8, '_'));
console.log(padLeft("teste e mais teste", 8, '_'));
console.log(padRight("teste", 8));
console.log(padRight("teste", 8, '_'));
console.log(padRight("teste e mais teste", 8, '_'));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/Pad.js).

Answer (score 7):

A partir do [ECMAScript 2017 (ES8)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html), foram implementados os seguintes métodos:

[`String.prototype.padStart(targetLength, padString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) e [`String.prototype.padEnd(targetLength, padString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd), que preenchem uma string com o conteúdo especificado até atingir um determinado comprimento.

Segue alguns exemplos de seu uso:

```js
let str = "abc";

console.log("padStart: " + str.padStart(1,"1"));
console.log("padStart: " + str.padStart(3,"1"));
console.log("padStart: " + str.padStart(6,123));
console.log("padStart: " + str.padStart(6,"%%%"));

console.log("----------------------");

console.log("padEnd: " + str.padEnd(1,"1"));
console.log("padEnd: " + str.padEnd(3,"1"));
console.log("padEnd: " + str.padEnd(6,123));
console.log("padEnd: " + str.padEnd(6,"%%%"));
```