# Como deixar um numero int com X casas numerais? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Quero saber se tem alguma propriedade em Javascript para caso o numero seja 5, apresente 005. caso 15, apresente 015.(3 casas)
Sem usar qualquer verificação no código e com a propriedade fazendo isso.

Comment: Acho que pode ajudar: [Existe alguma função que preenche uma string até determinado comprimento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/221602/125486).

Comment: Muito obrigado. Consegui agora!
Não vou apagar a pergunta para redirecionar caso alguem esteja com a mesma duvida.